# Pandas groupby - divide by the sum of all groups

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a DataFrame `df` and I create `gb = df.groupby("column1")`. Now I would like to do the following:

`x = gb.apply(lambda x: x["column2"].sum() / df["column2"].sum())`

It works but I would like to based everytinh on `x` not `x` and `df`. Ideally I expected that there is a function `x.get_source_df` and then my solution would be:

`x = gb.apply(lambda x: x["column2"].sum() / x.get_source_df()["column2"].sum())`

and in that case I could save this lambda function in a dictionary which I could use for any `df`. Is it possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

you should not use apply here, may be you find [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-not-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code) interesting, optimal method would be

```
df.groupby('column1')['column2'].sum().div(df['column2'].sum())
```

It works for more than one column too.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure in your explanation that you want to divide for the `sum` of each group or divide for the `sum` of the `entire` database. I assume what you want is to divide the sum of each group.

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['a']*5+['b']*5,
                   'year':[2001,2002,2003,2004,2005]*2,
                   'val1':[1,2,3,4,5,None,7,8,9,10],
                   'val2':[21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]})
```

Using `transform` then simply divide col by col:

```
df['sum'] = df.groupby('name')['val1'].transform(lambda g: g.sum())
df['weight'] = df['val1']/df['sum']
```